# What is the proper way to script Expect?

Tags: expect

I am quite new to Expect and am looking for some suggestions on this one:

I am trying to ssh to the servers and execute some commands.

If the server is one that I am logging into for the first time, it prompts me whether I want to trust it. I select "yes"; this is why I have the first `expect`. The second `expect` is for the password.

1. When I do the following, it accepts either the first prompt or the second prompt, so this does not work for me.

   ```
    expect {
       "yes/no" {
          send "yes\n"
       }
       "assword: " {
          send "$mypass\n"
       }
    }
   ```
2. When I do the following, it works, but it waits for a very long time before it enters the password. I suspect it waits for the "yes/no" prompt for a certain amount of time, does not receive it and then moves on

   ```
    expect "yes/no" {
          send "yes\n"
       }

    expect "assword: " {
          send "$mypass\n"
       }
   ```

What is the right way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you split it into two separate commands, you force the script to first look for the "yes/no" prompt. It will wait up to $timeout seconds (default 10 seconds). Only then will it look for the password prompt.

Your first idea is the right approach, but you're missing one key command:

```
expect {
   "yes/no" {
      send "yes\r"
      exp_continue    ;# <== this
   }
   "assword: " {
      send "$mypass\r"
   }
}
```

The `exp_continue` command essentially forces the flow of execution to remain in that Expect command so you can still match the password prompt.

A minor point: idiomatically, use `\r` (carriage return) as the character for "hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>".

For further learning, look at the [expect](/questions/tagged/expect) tag for more information and links to other questions and answers.

Comment: Another tip: when developing an expect script, add `exp_internal 1` to your code: that will enable (verbose!) debugging output and allow you to see how your patterns match (or, more importantly, don't match) the incoming text.

Comment: I got a lot of reading to do. Thanks for quick assistance Glenn ! I usually do "expect -d" on the very first line but I will attempt exp_internal 1 and try

Comment: `expect -d` == `exp_internal 1`